# AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'previousSibling' BS4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Scraping a table for a specific set of `'td'` tags and the text inside. To filter the scrape I'm targeting a specific `'img'` tag and trying to use a `previousSibling` call to get my desired `'td'`. I've tried `previousSibling`, `previous_sibling`, `previous` and keep getting the error:

> 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'previousSibling'

Any help would be appreciated. 
And this is my code so far.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-economic-calendar'
response = urlopen(base_url)
html = response
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'), "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table center td30'})
is_row = table.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'sprite sprite-common sprite-high-impact'}).previousSibling('td').text
print is_row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you are searching have no `siblings`. What you want (I think) is to get the image PARENT previous sibling.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-economic-calendar'
response = requests.get(base_url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf-8'), "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table center td30'})
is_row = table.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'sprite sprite-common 
sprite-high-impact'})

for row in is_row:
    print (row.parent.find_previous_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True))
```

Which outputs:

```
Fed's Yellen Speech
FOMC Member Kashkari Speech
BOE's Governor Carney speech
Claimant Count Change
BOC Rate Statement
BoC Interest Rate Decision
Bank of Canada Monetary Policy Report
BoC Press Conference
```

Comment: That would be exactly the answer. So, I needed the parent row and then previous sibling? - why both?

Comment: If you used `find_previous` you would get your image own parent, so you have to get your image parent before getting the previous `td`.

Comment: And, `previous_sibling` is to find nodes that are at the same level that the own that you are searching. The text you want is at the same level but with another parent.